# JavaScript to show varchar description of field on edit

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

I'm trying to implement a JavaScript to show the varchar description of a field, not the int value associated with the database row.

For instance, with the html element custType, instead of showing the primary key, to show its description, i.e., instead of 2, to show the word Domestic. I am using tabulator JQuery.

Right now, this code works perfectly, in terms of displaying the int for the primary key. I can change the value of the int and it, in turn, saves to the database. However, the int value is not useful to the end user. They have requested the descriptor column to appear.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Customers Admin Panel</title>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

</head>

<div>
    <select id="filter-field">
        <option></option>

        <option value="custId">Customer ID</option>
        <option value="custType">Customer Type</option>
        <option value="custName">Customer Name</option>
        <option value="groupId">Group ID</option>

    </select>

    <select id="filter-type">
        <option value="=">=</option>
        <option value="<"><</option>
        <option value="<="><=</option>
        <option value=">">></option>
        <option value=">=">>=</option>
        <option value="!=">!=</option>
        <option value="like">like</option>
    </select>

    <input id="filter-value" type="text" placeholder="value to filter">
</div>

<div id="example-table"></div>





<body onload="initTable()">
    <button onclick="loadCustomers()">Refresh Data</button>
    <table id="customers">
    </table>

    <script>



        var table;


        function handleCellUpdated(cell) {
            console.log(cell);
            console.log(cell.getRow());
            console.log(cell.getRow().getData());
            var record = cell.getRow().getData();

            $.ajax({
                url: "api/SalesTrackerCustomers/" + record.id,
                data: JSON.stringify(record),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: "PUT",
                success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
                    console.log("success")
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error) {
                    console.log("error")
                }
            });

        }


        function initTable() {

            //Build Tabulator
            table = new Tabulator("#customers", {
                height: "90vh",
                placeholder: "Loading...",
                addRowPos: "bottom",
                columns: [
                    { title: "Customer ID", field: "custId", width: 150, editor: "input" },
                    { title: "Customer Type", field: "custType", width: 130, editor: "input" },
                    { title: "Customer Name", field: "customerName", editor: "input" },
                    { title: "Group ID", field: "groupId", editor: "number" }
                ],
                cellEdited: handleCellUpdated
            });

            loadCustomers();
        }



        function loadCustomers() {
            console.log("loading data");
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/SalesTrackerCustomers",
                method: "GET"
            }).done(function (result) {

                table.setData(result);




            });
        }


        // javascript for search

        //Define variables for input elements
        var fieldEl = document.getElementById("filter-field");
        var typeEl = document.getElementById("filter-type");
        var valueEl = document.getElementById("filter-value");

        //Custom filter example
        function customFilter(data) {
            return data.car && data.rating < 3;
        }

        //Trigger setFilter function with correct parameters
        function updateFilter() {
            var filterVal = fieldEl.options[fieldEl.selectedIndex].value;
            var typeVal = typeEl.options[typeEl.selectedIndex].value;

            var filter = filterVal == "function" ? customFilter : filterVal;

            if (filterVal == "function") {
                typeEl.disabled = true;
                valueEl.disabled = true;
            } else {
                typeEl.disabled = false;
                valueEl.disabled = false;
            }

            if (filterVal) {
                table.setFilter(filter, typeVal, valueEl.value);
            }
        }

        //Update filters on value change
        document.getElementById("filter-field").addEventListener("change", updateFilter);
        document.getElementById("filter-type").addEventListener("change", updateFilter);
        document.getElementById("filter-value").addEventListener("keyup", updateFilter);

        //Clear filters on "Clear Filters" button click
        document.getElementById("filter-clear").addEventListener("click", function () {
            fieldEl.value = "";
            typeEl.value = "=";
            valueEl.value = "";

            table.clearFilter();
        });




    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

any examples would be helpful.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you can get the `int` value then you can get the associated `String` label. If the data is available, use it instead of the int. Are you asking about a lookup `formatter` that maps values to the display? I assume you don't want a free-form edit field as shown, rather you want to select between a fixed number of `custType`?

Comment: ker2x: its a .net c# core api web project

Comment: Dave: I'm asking for help displaying the varchar value, as opposed to the int value, in a way that does not interfere with Tabulator. I'm using Tabulator, out of the box it's  JQuery which allows you to rapidly develop a web app that displays a view, allows you to edit and delete. I do not know how to code this so that I display the varchar value, given the constraints of Tabulator.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a formatter, but we need a little more information to be sure.  How do you know that 2 maps to 'Domestic'?  Do you have an object that tells you that?  Something like, `{1: 'Not Domestic', 2: 'Domestic', 3: 'Something Else'}`.

Comment: hi nrayburn-tech: I have two tables, one is customers, it has two int fields and two varchar fields. The int fields map to two other tables, group and type. the field I really want to display to the user is nchar, and it is a word. I am being told the user cannot make changes (updates,deletes,adds) without seeing the value of the nchar on the screen.

Yes, you are absolutely correct...its just like you said in your comment or close enough.

Comment: How about the select or autocomplete editors from here?:
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/edit#edit-builtin